# Load html page in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Today I've found very strange method (as for me) of code structure. Website page calls itself using iframe. My question is : is it worth it? Could it be because of security issues? Thanks everyone in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Azerbaijan Technical University</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
        html, head, body, iframe{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:none;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <iframe id="frm" name="frmn" src="/" onload="location.hash = this.contentWindow.location.href.replace(this.contentWindow.location.origin,'');"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (location.hash && location.hash != '') {
            document.getElementById('frm').src = location.origin + location.hash.replace("#","");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('frm').src = "main.do"; //"/login";//
        }
    </script>
</body >
</html >
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, iframe is not recommended, even facebook and google wont allow you to put their site inside an iframe. You are making your site vulnerable to cross-site attack.